# Git: Changing my application architecture

Tags: git, gitlab

I maintain a repository of my code in GitLab. Due to architectural changes in my application, I need to maintain a separate version of repository which will be very different. But, I need to keep the old version too, for future development.

I know that **a new git branch** will serve the purpose. But, in my case, I need the branch to be permanently separated from the other branch. Please correct me if this is the right way, or suggest me otherwise.

Comment: Just clone the repository into a new one.

Comment: Yeah, it seems more easy to maintain. Thanks for the info.

Comment: But I want the different versions to co-exist under a same project repository.

Comment: Then make it a branch that can and will never be merged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with `git` you have to find yourself a workflow. Something that tells you when to branch, to tag, to clone and so on. I'm fond of the [feature branch one.](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow/)

Your case doesn't seem to fit in a branching case to me but you may find yourself comfortable working that way. Personally, I'd create another repository.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am leaning on to create another repository, except for the fact that, I want the different versions to co-exist under a same project repository.

Comment: I don't see your point... How are you leaning on to create another repo AND want that the versions co-exist under the same repo?

Comment: Yes, the two points are contradicting. I know I can't achieve both, and that was the dilemma. Proceeded on cloning into a new repository.